# how to find all places where certain method is called?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-assist

I have such method in one file:

```
virtual void addValue(FieldIdentityCPtr & identity, ValueType::Type type, const unsigned char * value, size_t length) = 0;
```

I want to find all places where this method is called. I.e. **all usages**.

I've tried to use VisualAssistX "Find References Alt+Shift+G" shortcut. And I actually receive **all references** to **any** (!) `addValue` methods.

I receive not only usage, but also methods declaration implementation etc.

I receive references to all methods with the same name. In my case I have ~10 more methods and references to all these methods are included too:

```
virtual void addValue(FieldIdentityCPtr & identity, ValueType::Type type, const int64 value) = 0;
virtual void addValue(FieldIdentityCPtr & identity, ValueType::Type type, const uint64 value) = 0;
virtual void addValue(FieldIdentityCPtr & identity, ValueType::Type type, const int32 value) = 0;
etc.
```

As a result 95% of the result is garbage and only 5% is something i'm looking for.

Is it possible to find **usages** of the certain method? If it is not possible to do using `VisualAssistX` then probably you can recommend another plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Rename the function to `addValueXXXX` and recompile.

The compiler will show you all the usages of the function.

Comment: adding a few letters and pressing F7 is tedious? it is 100% reliable and doesn't require VA license, what more could you want? :)

Comment: recompile takes time, sometimes quite long time. also you then need to rollback changes and recompile again.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains are really good at this stuff, and their IDE's are awesome code editors, with powerful features.

They do not have a C# IDE,  but they do have a plugin for visual studio called Resharper which provides a full find usages feature, and overcomes other short comings of the VS code editor.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

After installation the find usages functionality will be on the right click, context menu.

Comment: I have Resharper, thanks for clarifying which to use :)